# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined, while building ionic app for android

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm getting an error while running my ionic app for android and I'm not able to get the Problem.

Command:

```
$ sudo ionic cordova run android --prod --release --verbose
```

Output:

```
...
chunk {113} 113-es5.097d871d0097f5dc5442.js () 17.5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {114} 114-es2015.43745f337fb2fbc1341f.js () 4.12 kB  [rendered]
chunk {114} 114-es5.43745f337fb2fbc1341f.js () 5.24 kB  [rendered]
chunk {115} 115-es2015.8a0242b33fe8c077830a.js () 27.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {115} 115-es5.8a0242b33fe8c077830a.js () 27.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {13} styles.167082b7f296a73bbe8d.css (styles) 70.8 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {cordova} cordova.22d0b106f4dfd80eb9b7.js (cordova) 21 kB [entry] [rendered]
Date: 2019-10-08T16:21:29.118Z - Hash: 5c54472b0079875ceb26 - Time: 52527ms

Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.

   ng run app:ionic-cordova-build:production --platform=android exited with exit code 1.

   Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

The Error only appears on the prod release and I can't find a ".map()" in my whole project. Does someone has an Idea where this could come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove platform, update module and add platform again has fixed the bug in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually comes in case of object instantiation that existed without ().
So search for such instances in your codebase.

Comment: Can't find any object without (), slowly this error drives me crazy.

Comment: What is your @ionic/app-scripts  version ?